# Is it possible to call a .exe (compiled in qt) with an ajax-call and return a value from it to the response of that ajax-call?

Tags: php, c++, ajax, backend

Is it possible to call a .exe (compiled in qt) with an ajax-call and return a value from it to the response of that ajax-call?

At the moment i use Php. But the problem is if I want to give my programm to end-users that they can install/upload it on there server, everything is visible to them, cause php is not compiled. I need something compiled, thats why i think about the question above.

Hope somebody can help me

Comment: If you learn a bit more about the technology you are using (for example the http server), then you will learn that the question you ask does not really make too much sense... Obviously a "compiled .exe" (I shudder writing that expression...) can "be called" via internet (a, http server does nothing else and most of them _are_ "compiled". The fact if it was linked to a certain library is irrelevant in that.

Comment: You can call an .exe from PHP and get a result from it, yes.  (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)  Or your .exe itself can be the HTTP server which handles the AJAX call.  I guess it's not really clear to me which you're asking (or something else?), or where you're stuck.

Comment: @David: I'd say what the OP is looking for is how to use a "compiled program" as a CGI executable or as a http server module.

Comment: Your question reads as though the motivation for you to ask about a "compiled" solution is "protection of your intellectual property"... If that is the case, then please take a look around you and learn how the business works. Your code won't be stolen _if_ you provide a good service and good code quality, simply because it is more effective for others to pay you. Things are different obviously if you deliver bad quality, then you _should_ fear that you will not make good business when people can see that bad quality. But the answer to that is not secrecy. It is learning to code better.

Comment: thx for the answers. I want that i call the exe via the ajax-call and the exe should return a string or json. Is this now compiled program as a CGI executable or is this a server module?

Comment: Can i just put my exe in a folder on my server and make an ajax-call to it and receive the return-value of the exe in the ajax-response?